# Ok and Cancel button doesn't show on Flutter TimePicker

Tags: flutter, dart

I use showTimePicker() to show a time picker dialog on my flutter app. Everything works fine until someone complained that the Ok and Cancel button doesn't show on their device, so the picked time cannot be saved.

This is how it looks like on my (and most people's) app:
[image]

And this is how it looks like on the other phone:
[image]

I have seen a similar question here, this one: [Date/Time Picker Flutter : OK/CANCEL button not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922613/date-time-picker-flutter-ok-cancel-button-not-visible). But it seems like it's a different case cause in mine there is no space for the buttons at all, so i think it's not because of the font color.

I cannot debug on this device because it is a customer/client's phone. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Edit:

The device used where the bug happens is Samsung A33:
[image]

And i dont set the height for the dialog, i simply call showTimePicker() like this:

```
void pickStartTime() async {
    final time = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(selectedDate),
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
      confirmText: 'OK',
      cancelText: 'CANCEL',
    );
    if (time == null) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedDate = selectedDate.subtract(Duration(
        hours: selectedDate.hour,
        minutes: selectedDate.minute,
      ));
      selectedDate = selectedDate.add(Duration(
        hours: time.hour,
        minutes: time.minute,
      ));
    });
  }
```

Comment: what device models and android version buttons are not shown?

Comment: Did you set a height for your widget container? Can you post your widget code?

Comment: Maybe the widgets are "hidden below". Did you try to scroll down in the dialog?

Comment: @OMiShah i have updated my question to answer your questions

Comment: @sleepystar96 i have updated my question to answer your questions

Comment: @ValentinVignal unfortunately no:( i have asked the person to scroll down and he said he cant

Comment: @ajubo did you try specifying a Builder? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63385372/9824103

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following in your style:

```
<style name="TimePicker" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TimePicker">
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/borderlessButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="TimePicker.ImageButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TimePicker.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
</style>
```

This is the reason.